# How to use a loop for SQL parameter list to create an SQL string in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I want to use a function or a macro to create an SQL sentence by using a list filled with parameters formed like key-value.

e.g.:  `(("id" 3) ("version" 3) ("name" "foo") ("age" 10))`

I want to return a string like

`"insert into table ('id','version','name','age') values(3,3,'foo',10);"`

Here is my code:

```
(defvar *param* '(("id" 3) ("version" 3) ("name" "foo") ("age" 10)))

(defun dis (elt)
  (if (stringp elt)
      (concatenate 'string "'" elt "'")
      (write-to-string elt)))

(defun tostring (lst)
  (if (eql 1 (length lst))
      (dis (car lst))
      (concatenate 'string (dis (car lst)) "," (tostring (cdr lst)))))

(defun fillinsert (lst)
  (let ((keys (mapcar #'car lst))
        (values (mapcar #'cadr lst)))
    (concatenate 'string
                 "insert into table ("
                 (tostring keys)
                 ") values("
                 (tostring values)
                 ");")))
```

I do not know how to visit the list for only one time to create the string. 
Thanks

Comment: As a general rule, unless you are doing something for personal use only, don't do that. Use prepared statements from, for example `clsql` (example: http://clsql.b9.com/manual/sql-expression.html ). This will do some validation on what you are sending to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using `FORMAT` I wrote write the code below. The main idea is to use the usual output functions to create the contents as desired. The `WITHOUT-OUTPUT-TO-STRING` form then returns this output as a string - regardless how long the output and thus the string is. This way you don't have to create strings and concatenate strings all the time, which is both ugly and often inefficient.

```
(defun create-sql-sentence (kvl)
  (flet ((format-list (list key)
           (write-string "(")
           (loop for start = t then nil
                 for kv in list
                 for item = (funcall key kv)
                 unless start do (write-string ",")
                 do (typecase item
                      (string
                       (write-string "'")
                       (write-string item)
                       (write-string "'"))
                      (t
                       (write item))))
           (write-string ")")))                       
    (with-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
      (write-string "insert into table ")
      (format-list kvl #'first)
      (write-string " values")
      (format-list kvl #'second)
      (write-string ";"))))
```

Above does not use recursion.
It also does not use repeatedly `concatenated`.
It also does not repeatedly call `length`.

Comment: Oups, I think you mixed up the typecase cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a format solution:

```
CL-USER>
(setf *entry* '(("id" 3) ("version" 3) ("name" "foo") ("age" 10)))
(("id" 3) ("version" 3) ("name" "foo") ("age" 10))
CL-USER>
(format nil "insert into table (~{~S~^,~}) values (~{~S~^,~});"
        (mapcar #'first *entry*)
        (mapcar #'second *entry*))
"insert into table (\"id\",\"version\",\"name\",\"age\") values (3,3,\"foo\",10);"
CL-USER>
```

The format string uses the list (`~{`) directive to print the items in the list in a specified format. And it uses the tilde circumflex (`~^`) directive to disable the printing of the last comma at the far right of the list. The `~S` format directive ensures that each object is printed in a format that can be read back in by the Lisp reader. This means that the strings get surrounding quotes and the numbers do not.

I'm assuming that your SQL engine will interpret double quotes the same as single quotes. If single quotes are needed, than a bit more logic would be necessary to get things to work. One way to do that would be to extend the format directives and define your own `~` that surrounds strings with single quotes. But I didn't do this since IME most SQL engines interpret double quotes the same as single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you wnat to use `loop` to build your string, and to traverse the list only once, you can use the [destructuring](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/06_aag.htm) feature of loop. Your function `fillinsert` can then be defined like this like this:

```
(defun fillinsert (lst)
  (loop for (key value) in lst
        collect key into keys
        collect value into values
        finally (return (concatenate 'string
                                     "insert into table ("
                                     (tostring keys)
                                     ") values("
                                     (tostring values)
                                      ");")))
```

or (using `format` to buld the string):

```
(defun fillinsert (lst)
  (loop for (key value) in lst
        collect key into keys
        collect value into values
        finally (return (format nil
                                "insert into table (~a) values (~a);"
                                (tostring keys)
                                (tostring values)))))
```